# Display all page which have not a certain template

Tags: templates

I'm trying to display all pages of my website which have not the following template: `template-rubrique.php`.
It works great but it doesn't output the blog page as well, since it doesn't have a template at all.

How should I proceed?

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'page',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'order'          => 'ASC',
  'orderby'        => 'title',
  'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
      'key'       => '_wp_page_template',
      'value'     => 'template-rubrique.php',
      'compare'   => '!=',
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `OR` relation to the meta query and also get pages with no `_wp_page_template` meta key:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'  => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'template-rubrique.php',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        )

    )
);
```